# Can I use revtex, babel + BibTex, and cleveref together?

Tags: bibtex, babel, cleveref, revtex

I am trying to write a paper with

- `revtex4-2` document class (`revtex4-2 2020/10/03 4.2e`);
- `.bib` file specifying `language` field for some entries;
- `cleveref` package;
- custom theorem (using `\newtheorem` command and `\Crefname` for references in `cleveref` to work correctly).

This, however, results in a compilation failure. Here is a minimal example:

`min.tex`:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{myproposition}{Proposition}
\Crefname{myproposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}

\begin{document}
\cite{web:lang:stats}
\bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

`myrefs.bib`:

```
@misc{web:lang:stats,
  author = {W3Techs},
  title = {Usage Statistics of Content Languages for Websites},
  language = {English},
  year = {2017},
  note = {Last accessed 16 September 2017},
  url = {http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_language/all}
}
```

If I put these two files into the same directory with nothing else in it (remove all temp files from previous compilations to make a clean experiment) and run

```
pdflatex min.tex && bibtex min.aux && pdflatex min.tex
```

I get

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\extrasenglish ->\extrasenglish 
                                \crefname {myproposition}{\MakeLowercase Pro...
l.12 \babel@aux{english}{}
```

Why? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `babel` because of the `language` field in the bib item. But you need to pass a language to `babel`. Best to add the language in the global options to `\documentclass`, so also `cleveref` will pick it.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{web:lang:stats,
  author = {W3Techs},
  title = {Usage Statistics of Content Languages for Websites},
    language = {English},
  year = {2017},
  note = {Last accessed 16 September 2017},
  url = {http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_language/all}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[english]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{myproposition}{Proposition}
\Crefname{myproposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}

\begin{document}
\cite{web:lang:stats}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if you just use (American) English, you can remove the `language` field in the bib item(s) and not load `babel`.

**Note.** I used `filecontents*` with `\jobname.bib` just not to clobber my files. Use your own file and remove `filecontents*`.